# Questions without citation

Tags: discussion

[This](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/26322/15723) is an answer to one of the questions in Academia. Although the writer has supported his answer with good references, but he has never brought a list of the papers he has cited at the end of his post.

Is there any need to rise a Flag to inform the moderators about such problem in the answer or one may just leave a comment on the answer and wait for the writer to provide required citation information (if he edit his answer or not)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can **request** that other users add complete citations. You cannot **demand** it, and it's not a "flaggable" offense.

Comment: How others are sure, which exact publications he is referring to? I mean, this seems something that the writer himself should edit.

Comment: Yes, and you can ask the author of the answer politely in a comment to do so. But the point is that it's unreasonable to delete an otherwise acceptable answer because the author used "short" citations instead of full ones.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks.